# Ограничение размера шрифта

Tags: css3, html5

Хочу сделать блочные ссылки расположенные горизонтально. Но при приближении текст ссылок выходит за границы блока. У блоков есть ограничение по высоте, чтобы при приближении смотрелось симпатично.

```css
header {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(209, 208, 206, 0.6);
  height: 22vh;
  z-index: 5;
  width: 100%;
}

nav#menu {
  height: 3rem;
  position: relative;
  top: 14vh;
  max-height: 7vh;
}

nav#menu ul.left {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: 5vh;
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

nav#menu ul.left li {
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

nav#menu ul li a {
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <nav id="menu">
      <ul class="left">
        <li><a href="/">Главная</a></li>
        <li><a href="/about">О нас</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Как сделать, чтобы текст в ссылках не выходил за границы блока и не выглядел огромным при приближении? Можно ли как-то ограничить приближение сайта мышкой на компьютере (в `google chrome` возможно приближение до 500%) ?

Comment: Если честно, не понятно, для чего ты пытаешь адаптировать сайт при масштабировании на 500% ??7

Comment: Просто хочется чтобы сайт выглядел красиво и при увеличении масштаба.